# Difficulty extending tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I'm using Python 3.9.6. Why do the classes `A` and `B` work with the `*args` as a parameter, but `C` does not? Python throws this error (before printing `args`):

`TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 3`.

Note the only difference between the classes is if it is extending a class, and what class it's extending. I'm asking because I'm trying to make an object that behaves exactly like a tuple but would be distinguishable from it using `isinstance`.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(args)

class B(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(args)
        super().__init__(args)

class C(tuple):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(args)
        super().__init__(args)

A(1,2,3)
B(4,5,6)
C(7,8,9)
```

Comment: `tuple`, as an immutable type, does its initialization in the `__new__()` method, rather than `__init__()`.  You've overridden the wrong method to change the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your example class `C`, the value `(7, 8, 9)` is not printed before the error message is shown. That means your `__init__` method is not being called at all.

In fact, the error is raised by the `__new__` method, not the `__init__` method. It looks like the difference between `B` and `C` is caused by the fact that `list.__new__` accepts any number of arguments (and ignores them), whereas `tuple.__new__` does not:

```py
>>> list.__new__(B, 4, 5, 6)
[]
>>> tuple.__new__(C, 7, 8, 9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 3
```

Note that `list.__new__` just creates the list object, it doesn't populate it (`list.__init__` does that). I can't say for certain why one accepts extra arguments while the other doesn't, but that's the reason for this discrepancy, anyway.

To fix it, your class `C` needs to override `__new__` in order to pass the correct number of arguments to `tuple.__new__`:

```py
class C(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        print(args)
        return super().__new__(cls, args)
```

In this case there is no need to also override `__init__`, though you still can if you want to; however, note that `tuple` doesn't override `__init__`, so your `super().__init__()` will actually invoke `object.__init__`, which accepts no arguments and does nothing, so you must invoke it with no arguments.

Comment: `I can't say for certain why one accepts extra arguments while the other doesn't`: It is explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__): _"__new__() is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation."_

Comment: @Selcuk I'm not sure how raising an error makes it easier for subclasses to do that, and it also doesn't explain why `list.__new__` behaves differently. Probably the difference is more like an implementation detail; they could have made `tuple.__new__` accept any number of arguments like `list.__new__` did, and then have `tuple.__init__` check for the correct number (as `list.__init__` does), but because `tuple.__new__` already exists, perhaps they chose to have this be enforced by `__new__` rather than write an `__init__` method just to enforce this.